# HOWTO: Call a php file from .htaccess for 3 different conditions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to, in a .htaccess file, check three conditions and - if any of them applies - rewrite the url in one go.
To rewrite the url, I created a php file:

```
<?php
$sURL = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo '$sURL = ' . $sURL . '<br />';
$sURL = strtolower($sURL);
if (substr($sURL, 0, 4) != 'www.') {
    $sURL = 'www.' . $sURL;
}
if (substr($sURL, -10) == 'index.html') {
    $sURL = substr($sURL, 0, -10);
}
echo 'Location: http://' . $sURL;
#header('Location: http://' . $sURL, true, 301);
?>
```

(echo's are for testing purposes, they will be removed and the header() line activated as soon as it works).
The output of this file is correct, I checked that with different url's.

My problem now is how to properly define the conditions for calling this file in the .htaccess file.
The conditions are:

- missing www.
- trailing "index.html" (must be removed)
- CAPS (must be converted to lowercase)

This is what I have in the .htaccess for now:

```
    RewriteRule \.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|pdf)$ - [NC,QSA,L]

#    RewriteRule ([A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]
#    RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:FALSE,S=1]
#    RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)index\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) main.redirect.php [QSA,L]
```

I had it working for the first and second condition, without the commented lines, with OR on both RewriteCond lines, but after I put the HASCAPS part in, that wouldn't work again even though I commented the HASCAPS part out.

I worked on this for hours now, but I can't find what's wrong.
Any help, even hints in the right direction, is gladly appreciated!

Kind regards

René

EDIT:

I'm going through it step by step now (means every contition on it's own), and I am wodering why this works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html $1 [R=301,L]
```

while this doesn't:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) main.redirect.php [QSA,L]
```

And this one doesn't work as well:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html main.redirect.php [L]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I upvoted to neutralize the downvote. I guess it was because you don't call php files from .htaccess but I am no professional in this matter.

Comment: Thanks Theolodis! Well, the last call in the .htaccess almost always goes to either an html or php file. In the .htaccess you can only redirect the browser, or call a file.

Comment: This looks like a question for serverfault.com because it's more about Apache configuration. Anyway you should probably tell what you want to achieve in the end, because it looks like you are going to redirect with your PHP file, too, and you might be better off doing everything through Apache redirects.